# Hiding row in Birt on if some value is empty

Tags: java, birt

I want to hide the row if the value does not contain anything in birt. I have added the below expression in visibility expression of the row :

```
var val = JSON.parse(dataSetRow["deviceStatus.errorCode"])
var result="";
for(var t=0 ; t<val.length; t++)
{
    if(val[t])
        result = val[t] + "," + result;
}
result != null;
```

I want to hide it, if result does not contain anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just the below code in the expression to make it to work, I changed the dataSetRow to row and used if statement :

```
var val = JSON.parse(row["deviceStatus.errorCode"])
var result="";
for(var t=0 ; t<val.length; t++){
    if(val[t]){
        result = val[t] + ","+result
    }
}
if(result){
    false
}else{
    true
}
```